# Flutter container overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to display image inside a container with responsive width and height.

Here is my code:

```
 ...
 child: Column (
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
       Row (
          children: [
             Padding (
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Container(
                   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *.3,
                   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                         image: AssetImage("assets/images/gunung.jpg"),
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ...
```

here is the output:

[image]

Is there any solutions?

Comment: hmmm i suggest to use a package for putting sizes so that u wont worry on to it package like flutter utils or sizer it auto the sizes on each orientation you want. But if you dont want it try layout builder if the screen is in land you can put the own size on it.

Comment: I've tried using Sizer but I got an error saying "lateinitializationerror field 'height' has not been initialized"

Comment: @ArbiterChil You don't need to use a package for basics of Flutter. Using a package simply increases your app dependency and size when you don't need one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Change this to your code :

//Add `Exapanded widget`

---

```
 child: Column (
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
           Row (
              children: [
    //Add Expanded Widget it will solve your issue 
    Expanded(
                 Padding (
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Container(
                       height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *.3,
                       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                             image: AssetImage("assets/images/gunung.jpg"),
                             fit: BoxFit.cover,
```

Comment: this works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set the `width` of your `Container` as

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1
```

This means that it'll take up the width space of your device screen.

Not to mention, you've also set the `Padding` too. And that is taking up left, top, right and bottom spacing of 20.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)
```

This `Padding` is taking your `Container` ahead than it needs to go, hence the overflow.

There are many ways to fix this.

1. You could subtract the padding from the width that you've initialized for your container. 20 from the left and 20 from the right.

```
(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1) - 20 - 20
```

2. You could set the padding within the container itself. You probably don't need `Padding` widget separately hanging around above `Container`.

```
    Padding(                                  // <---- remove
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),            // <---- remove
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *.3,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),    // <---- use this
        ...
```

Comment: what about the padding around the container? tried using margin but it overflows